# SQL Update table with cumulative value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Date  |StockCode|DaysMovement|OnHand
29-Jul|SC123    |30          |500
28-Jul|SC123    |15          |NULL
27-Jul|SC123    |0           |NULL
26-Jul|SC123    |4           |NULL
25-Jul|SC123    |-2          |NULL
24-Jul|SC123    |0           |NULL
```

The reason only the top row has an OnHand value is because I can get this from another table that stores the current qty on hand for any stock code.

The other records in the table are taken from another table that logs all the movement for any given day.

I want to update the above table so that the OnHand column shows the QtyOnHand for that row's date based on the previous record's stock and movement, such that is looks like this at the end of the update:

```
Date  |StockCode|DaysMovement|OnHand
29-Jul|SC123    |30          |500
28-Jul|SC123    |15          |470
27-Jul|SC123    |0           |455
26-Jul|SC123    |4           |455
25-Jul|SC123    |-2          |451
24-Jul|SC123    |0           |453
```

I'm currently achieving this with a CURSOR.  But performance really sucks over thousands of records.

Is there some SET-based UPDATE statement I can run that will achieve the same result?

Comment: what sql server you have?

Comment: Specifically, do you have SQL Server 2012 or later, or not? SQL Server 2012 introduced the LAG function, which will do precisely what you're asking. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx.

Comment: I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9164/33)**)

```
DECLARE @Movement INT , @OnHandRunning INT  

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 percent DaysMovement, OnHand 
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY [StockCode], [Date] DESC
)
UPDATE CTE SET @OnHandRunning = OnHand = COALESCE(@OnHandRunning - @Movement, OnHand),
               @Movement = DaysMovement
```

**UPDATE:** For multiple `StockCodes` you can modify above query like below (**[Fiddle demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10f26/1)**):

```
DECLARE @Movement INT , @OnHandRunning INT, @StockCode VARCHAR(10) = '' 

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 percent DaysMovement, OnHand, StockCode  
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY [StockCode],[Date] DESC
)
UPDATE CTE SET @OnHandRunning = OnHand = 
       CASE WHEN @StockCode<> StockCode THEN OnHand ELSE @OnHandRunning - @Movement END,
       @Movement = DaysMovement,
       @StockCode = StockCode
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea. I had no idea you could use variable + coalesce dynamically on a result set like that. :)

Comment: this does indeed run frickin' fast, but sadly the logic falls over when the entire dataset of more than one stockcode comes into play.  The totals of the one stock code roll over to the next.

Comment: @ShawndeWet couldn't you just add a where statement to ressolve that ? WHERE Date >= '2014-07-01' and Date < '2014-08-01'

Comment: I've just never used a CTE before and don't know what gotcha's there may be.

Comment: CTE is for [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). Have you replaced `Table1` with correct table name? Or do you get any error messages?

Comment: Nevermind sorry my bad it is updating the underlying table...just not as I am expecting it to.  Will dig deeper to figure out why.

Comment: Wow I've just figured out that despite the ORDER BY in your UPDATE CTE statement, the actual sequence in which the rows are inserted into the base table is the sequence in which the base table is updated by the UPDATE statement!  This is a NASTY gotcha.

Comment: Chose this one as the answer because it is definitely the most performant!  (Just beware of the Gotcha mentioned above).  I got around this problem by applying a PK to the table, and removed the ORDER BY from the UPDATE CTE statement)

Answer (score 2):

This works, no idea how it performs compared to a cursor though?

```
--Data
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [Date] DATE,
    StockCode VARCHAR(50),
    DaysMovement INT,
    OnHand INT);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140729', 'SC123', 30, 500);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140728', 'SC123', 15, NULL);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140727', 'SC123', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140726', 'SC123', 4, NULL);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140725', 'SC123', -2, NULL);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20140724', 'SC123', 0, NULL);

--Query
SELECT 
    t1.[Date], 
    t1.StockCode, 
    t1.DaysMovement, 
    CASE WHEN t1.OnHand IS NULL THEN MAX(t2.OnHand) - SUM(t2.DaysMovement) ELSE t1.OnHand END AS OnHand 
FROM 
    @Table t1 
    LEFT JOIN @Table t2 ON t1.[Date] < t2.[Date]
GROUP BY 
    t1.[Date], 
    t1.StockCode, 
    t1.DaysMovement, 
    t1.OnHand
ORDER BY 
    t1.[Date] DESC;
```

Results are:

```
Date        StockCode   DaysMovement    OnHand
2014-07-29  SC123       30              500
2014-07-28  SC123       15              470
2014-07-27  SC123       0               455
2014-07-26  SC123       4               455
2014-07-25  SC123       -2              451
2014-07-24  SC123       0               453
```

Comment: @Darka this is not updating the table. Nor is your answer.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk come on. Maybe should we also come to his place and do it for him?? :D

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't use `LAG`, you can try Recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ([Date] VARCHAR(100), StockCode VARCHAR(100), DaysMovement INT, OnHand INT)


INSERT INTO @table SELECT '29-Jul', 'SC123', 30, 500
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '28-Jul', 'SC123', 15, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '27-Jul', 'SC123', 0, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '26-Jul', 'SC123', 4, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '25-Jul', 'SC123', -2, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '24-Jul', 'SC123', 0, NULL


INSERT INTO @table SELECT '19-Jul', 'SC1234', 30, 500
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '18-Jul', 'SC1234', 15, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '17-Jul', 'SC1234', 0, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '16-Jul', 'SC1234', 4, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '15-Jul', 'SC1234', -2, NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '14-Jul', 'SC1234', 0, NULL


;WITH addRowID As (

    SELECT [Date], StockCode, DaysMovement, OnHand, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode ORDER BY StockCode, [Date] DESC) AS ROWID
    FROM @table

), CTE AS (
    SELECT [Date], StockCode, DaysMovement, OnHand, ROWID
    FROM addRowID 
    WHERE OnHand IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT D.[Date], D.StockCode, D.DaysMovement, C.OnHand - C.DaysMovement AS OnHand, D.ROWID
    FROM CTE AS C
    INNER JOIN addRowID AS D
        ON D.StockCode = C.StockCode
        AND D.ROWID = C.ROWID + 1
    WHERE D.OnHand IS NULL

)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
```

Instead of last `SELECT` you can put update. Not sure about performance....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using sqlserver 2012+, that would make this alot easier. Try this. It will UPDATE your table:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Date date, StockCode char(5), DaysMovement int, OnHand int)

INSERT @t VALUES
('29-Jul-2014','SC123',30,500),
('28-Jul-2014','SC123',15,NULL),
('27-Jul-2014','SC123',0 ,NULL),
('26-Jul-2014','SC123',4 ,NULL),
('25-Jul-2014','SC123',-2,NULL),
('24-Jul-2014','SC123',0 ,NULL)

;WITH cte as
(
  SELECT
    Date, 
    StockCode,
    DaysMovement,
    OnHand, 
    max(case when Date = '2014-07-29' THEN OnHand END) over() BaseOnhand, 
    Calc.MovementChange
  FROM @t t
  CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT
     coalesce(SUM(DaysMovement), 0) MovementChange 
   FROM @t
   WHERE
     Date between DateAdd(Day, 1, t.Date) and '2014-07-29'
  ) calc
)
UPDATE CTE SET OnHand = BaseOnhand - MovementChange

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Result:

```
Date        StockCode DaysMovement OnHand
2014-07-29  SC123     30           500
2014-07-28  SC123     15           470
2014-07-27  SC123     0            455
2014-07-26  SC123     4            455
2014-07-25  SC123     -2           451
2014-07-24  SC123     0            453
```

Comment: anyway yours also nice. Different approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQLServer 2008 or an older version a triangular `JOIN` is a easy way to solve this

```
SELECT a.[Date], a.StockCode, a.DaysMovement
     , OnHand = MAX(b.OnHand) - SUM(b.DaysMovement) + a.DaysMovement
FROM   Table1 a
       LEFT JOIN Table1 b ON a.StockCode = b.StockCode AND b.[Date] >= a.[Date]
GROUP BY a.[Date], a.StockCode, a.DaysMovement
ORDER BY a.[Date] DESC
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9164/25)</kbd>

If you have SQLServer 2012 or better the possibility to use `ORDER` in the windowing function make the query easier

```
SELECT [Date], StockCode, DaysMovement
     , OnHand = MAX(OnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode)
              - SUM(DaysMovement) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode 
                                        ORDER BY [Date] Desc)
              + DaysMovement
FROM   Table1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9164/2)</kbd>

Both queries use the same logic: for each row get the only value of `OnHand` (using `MAX` and remove the movement of every day after the current, doing this it'll be removed also the current day movement, so it's added up. This logic avoid the null value in the first (last) day of every `StockCode`.

The `UPDATE` is easily derived, using a `WITH` if you have SQLServer 2005 or better (in this I use the SQLServer 2012 or better version)

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT [Date], StockCode, DaysMovement
       , OnHand = MAX(OnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode)
                - SUM(DaysMovement) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode 
                                          ORDER BY [Date] Desc)
                + DaysMovement
  FROM   Table1
)
UPDATE Table1 SET
  OnHand = A.OnHand
FROM Table1
     INNER JOIN A ON Table1.StockCode = a.StockCode AND Table1.[Date] = a.[Date]
```