# Trying to update temporary table in sql by accumulating variable

Tags: sql, sql-update, temp-tables, accumulate

I have a temp table that contains 4 variables that I need to do a calculation to and then accumulate that field from record to record, similar to a cumulative sum.  I have setup a RANK in the #TEMP_TABLE_1.  Here is my code:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.TOTAL_NET_BAL = ISNULL((SELECT T2.TOTAL_NET_BAL 
                               FROM #TEMP_TABLE_1 AS T2
                               WHERE T1.RANK - 1 = T2.RANK),0) + (T1.MAX_STD_CAPACITY + T1.MAX_QT_CAPACITY) - (T1.STANDARD_PANELS + T1.QUICKTURN_PANELS)
FROM #TEMP_TABLE_1 AS T1
```

All this is doing is updating the current row in the table for TOTAL_NET_BAL.  For some reason, it is not grabbing the amount when we are on the next row.

[image: Image of sample data here]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: `R MSC MQC SP QP TOTAL_NET_BAL
582 340 100 209 0 231
583 340 100 361 0 310
584 340 100 32 45 673
585 340 100 153 0 960
586 340 100 799 0 601
587 0 0 0 0 601
588 0 0 0 0 601
`

Comment: Please include this in your Question as formatted code, not in a comment.

Comment: Here are 2 lines.  Note the TOTAL_NET_BAL is what I am trying to accumulate.Here are two records.RANK = 582
MSP = 340
MQC=100
SP=209
QP=0
TOTNETBAL=231

RANK = 583
MSP = 340
MQC=100
SP=361
QP=0
TOTNETBAL=310

Comment: Thank you Scratte for the idea.  New to this board.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a cumulative sum. You can see how to do a cumulative sum at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010794/sql-update-table-with-cumulative-value) and adapt that to fit your need.

Comment: Thank you Jason.  I actually think I know how to do the cumulative sum.  Based on the logic of my code, I don't understand why that doesn't work.

Comment: When using set commands (SQL), you have no guarantee in which order the individual rows within the set will be processed. (That's what cursors are for.) To maintain atomicity, a multi-row update won't reference data from any other row affected by that same update. Your _changes_ are in the transaction but your temp table is pulling from the actual table. Cursors get around this by working on one row at a time, and CTEs are a fancy (and more efficient?) way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was changing my code to another select statement into another TEMP table using the SUM function.  Still don't know why my original SQL statement up top wouldn't work but I am able to move on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE.  If I understand correctly, you want a running sum:

```
with toupdate as (TOTAL_NET_BAL) over 
      select t.*,
             sum((T1.MAX_STD_CAPACITY + T1.MAX_QT_CAPACITY) - (T1.STANDARD_PANELS + T1.QUICKTURN_PANELS)) over (order by rank) as running_total
      from #temp_table t
update toupdate
    set total_net_bal = running_total;
```